# Error while loading shared libraries php

Tags: 16.04, php

I reinstalled php due to some errors. After installing it I got this error `php: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` while just running `php -v`. The `php7.0` and `php7.1` command is working. I've tried reinstalling php again, reinstalling `libssl`, but nothing seems to work. Does somebody know what to do in this situation?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say php7.1 must come from 17.10? It requires a newer libssl than what is in 17.04. Does this sound familiar? Where did you get php7.1? What flavour/version OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I installed php with `sudo apt-get install php-fpm`. The weird thing is when i run php directly from `/usr/bin` it works, but otherwise not.

Comment: Do you have the `proposed` repo enabled? `sudo apt-get install php-fpm` should have installed php7.0. I'd uninstall php7.1.

Comment: No, just "unsupported updates". Before I reinstalled I had php7.0

Comment: Well... you just proved my point. You enabled a repo for `unsupported updates`, and you got php7.1. As I said before, I'd uninstall `php7.1` and uncheck `unsupported updates`. Let me make that into an answer and maybe you can accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

`libssl.so.1.0.2` doesn't exist, and `php7.1` isn't supported, on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. You got `php7.1` installed by enabling the `Unsupported Updates` repository. Disable this repository, and uninstall php7.1.

Comment: Downgraded to `php7.0` but still getting the error. Is there a way to reinstall `libssl.so.1.0.2` ?

Comment: `libssl.so.1.0.2` doesn't even exist on 17.04. Did you `remove` php7.1 or did you `purge` it to remove all of the configuration files?

Comment: Then why is it asking for it? :S I ran `sudo apt-get purge php-*`.

Comment: You may have left a dependency installed. Do `dpkg -l *php* | grep ii` and see if you find any 7.1 stuff still installed.

Comment: Hm.. There was only `php7.0` files.

Comment: Did you reboot after purging php7.1? Well... you can try purging the php7.0 stuff (all the php stuff)... and reinstalling php7.0 after the error message is eliminated... however... I can't tell you what side-effects there might be by doing that. Apache might throw a fit. When you installed unsupported software, untangling the mess may take extra effort. (keep the list generated by the dpkg command so you'll know what to reinstall).

Comment: @Murillio4 status please?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/usr/bin` and check what php files are there:

```
cd /usr/bin
ls -al php*
```

You will see the php file along with the new php files like `php7.0` or `php7.2`

Move php to php1 just to free the php name with the following command:

```
sudo mv php php1
sudo mv php7.0 php
```

So, in php now you have version 7.0.

With this your Apache2 will keep its php version and only the cli commands will use the newer version.